# Install old PHP version on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have got an `Ubuntu14.04` and a `PHP 5.5.9` installed.
Now I need `PHP 5.4.*`

As I have seen, it is not possible to downgrade it.
I have to purge it and then install the old version.

I have searched everywhere but I can't find an instruction how to get an old PHP version which works.

I already tried to get it with `apt-get install php5=version`, but `apt-cache policy php5` does always only show `PHP 5.5.9`
And also 
`wget php5.4....`
`./configure`
make
make install
doesn't work.

What is the solution for my problem?

Comment: exactly what isn't working? getting php 5.4? installing php 5.4? having php5.4 show up in apache instead of 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

Download Apache http and PHP from source and it can be done.

Choose an installation source location; personally I use /usr/local/src but I've seen many alternatives.

Download Apache HTTP of the appropriate version (probably 2.4, I use the tar.gz files) http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Download your PHP http://php.net/get/php-5.4.42.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

You will need to unzip (`tar -zxvf`), configure, make, make install both httpd and php.  There are tons of configuration options you'll need to consider with both.  You may hit many obstacles along the way and need to install various packages with apt-get but don't despair - search for the errors and you will find help, [for example](http://www.omniweb.com/wordpress/?p=1040)

Before you begin installing, make sure you've completely removed all remnants of php5.5

Good luck and post your results.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to .htaccess to downgrade php version to 5.4

```html
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
```

for more details check this link
https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/manually-set-the-version-of-php-using-an-htaccess-file-a614325.html

Comment: But do I need to have 5.4 installed to use this? Because I can't install it.