# Install older php version on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I had a problem with the update of PHP and i need to return to php 5.5.x,i do a lot of tutorials and finally had this. The question is, when i  try to install, all times install 5.6, how change the 'candidate' to install?

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy php5

php5:
      Instalados: (ninguno)
      Candidato:  5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6
      Tabla de versión:
         5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 0
            500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
         5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 0
            500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install old PHP version on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982265/install-old-php-version-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Using PPA is easiest:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php5=5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
```

If you already imported PPA, what is obvious from your question, execute only last two lines. You also need to prevent updates from php 5.5 to php 5.6

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold php5
```